# R: Create list with vector based on siblings in one go

Tags: r

A problem that i frequently encounter when creating lists, data frames etc. is, that some vectors are to be created in dependence on other vectors in that list.

Example:

```
mylist <- list(
    norm_mean = 50,
    norm_sd = 10,
    norm_values =  qnorm(seq(0.0001,0.9999, 0.0001), norm_mean, norm_sd)
)
```

Of course this doesn't work:

```
Error in qnorm(seq(1e-04, 0.9999, 1e-04), norm_mean, norm_sd) : 
  object 'norm_mean' not found
```

I don't want to create a list with `norm_mean` and `norm_sd` and later add `norm_values`, but do this in one go. I assume that there's `tidyverse` solution to this?!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function

```
mylist <- function(
    norm_mean,
    norm_sd,
    norm_values =  qnorm(seq(0.0001,0.9999, 0.0001), norm_mean, norm_sd)
){
    return(list(norm_mean = norm_mean, norm_sd = norm_sd, norm_values = norm_values))
}
mylist(50, 10)$norm_values
```

Comment: Nice one, maybe make the function to get the `mean` and `sd` as inputs?